# How to edit a table class variable in order to add a dimname?

Tags: r, attributes

I would like to add a dimname to a table class variable :

```
>v = table(c("b"))

b 
1 

> attributes(v)
$dim
[1] 1

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
[1] "b"


$class
[1] "table"
```

I would like to set the `$dim` attribute to `2` and the `$dimnames[[1]]` attribute to `[1] "a" "b"` so when I call `v` I get :

```
>v

a b 
0 1
```

Note that `"a"` would have to be associated with the value `0`. Is it even possible ?

Comment: `v[2] <- 0; names(v)[2] <- "a"; sort(v)` will do it, but I'm not sure why you'd want this if `a` is not in your original data

Comment: This works ty. I needed to format my output.

Comment: `table(factor(c("b"),levels=c("a","b") ))` ?

Comment: @RichardScriven can you post that as an answer so Wicelo can accept it as the correct one?

Comment: I think @thelatemail should post his answer, as it makes more sense.